# Android Dev: sending push notification(message/link) from server(.net) to all devices having the app

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to the push notification subjet for android and I have an application with a .net web server as well as a remote database. I want to send a notification to all users which opens in a new intent. I have read about GCM and other third party platforms, but I was confused when they mention device registration ID, as I do not know how to get all the ids of all devices installing the app I am developping. Any straightforward tutorial or code helping me solve the confusion please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can not provide complete answer to your question asked. But still it can help you.

GCM process works in this way.

1. at the first launch, your application will get the registration id from Google GCM server and give it to application server. Now the application server has all the registration ids in which your app is running.
2. Now you can easily dispatch push message for all devices.

Comment: can you suggest a tutorial for GCM sending notifications to all users with the application on device?